# Removing multiple consecutive periods from file names

Tags: powershell

I am working on cleaning up a file share for a SharePoint migration, and I am writing a script to either remove or replace unwanted characters from file names.  I am struggling to remove multiple consecutive periods (file..example.txt as an example of what I am dealing with).

I was able to use the simple replace script below to deal with all of the other objectionable characters, but the script fails when attempting to replace double period errors.

```
dir -recurse | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace ".." , ""}
```

I expect that a file with a name like file..example.txt to become fileexample.txt, however nothing changes.

Comment: -replace uses regex and period is a meta character. What you want is `$_.name -replace "\.+", "."` which will replace any group of periods with just one. ex. `"hello..this .....is ... me." -replace "\.+", "."` would give `hello.this .is . me.`

Comment: Agreeing with @Matt an alternative RegEx is `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\.+(?=\.)'}` it doesn't need a replacement string as it removes all consequtive dot's except the last as a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Matt mentioned in the comments, `-replace` uses regex. In regex, the `.` character is a wildcard representing any single character. To actually select a dot, you must use `\.`.

The regex for selecting anything with two or more dots is `\.\.+` ([RegExr](https://regexr.com/4f5pp))

Therefore, your command should be:

```
dir -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "\.\.+" , ""}
```

However, `dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`. It's a good practice when writing scripts to avoid aliases whenever possible as it can create a situation where your script does not work in certain environments. With that in mind, your command should be:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "\.\.+" , ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .replace() instead, and not have to worry about the regex.  Note that Rename-Item is using a delay bind script block https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-5.1

```
Get-Childitem -Recurse -Filter *..* | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('..','.') } -WhatIf
```

Comment: This works as long as you only want to replace two consecutive dots, which may or may not be what @daustindev needed